# US term for potential increase in earnings from employer?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

What term(s) do Americans use when an employee might get more money from their employer, usually happening on a yearly basis?  Perhaps Wage review?  Salary review?  Or even a more generic Annual review?  However, the latter doesn't emphasize money so I'd rather have term(s) that do.

Comment: This really too broad, as it varies with company and industry. I have usually seen "Performance Reviews", which includes both performance and compensation, when compensation is based on performance. On the other hand, union workers may have an increase in compensation based on contractual agreements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An increase in salary is called a raise; a one-time extra payment is called a bonus. The review itself can have different names at different organizations, but in my experience, it's most typically called an "annual review."

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Nice first answer! it would help if you add links to references, for example dictionary definitions of the words raise and bonus.

Comment: It's always a review; if your procedures seperate things you may have a preformance review and a salary review semi-independantly, or they might be lumped together as annual review or even performance review. There are probably other terms used at specific companies but these will be understood by anyone with office experience.